# sell ebooks in app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I will be making an iPhone app that will sell ebooks. we have a website version of this and we want to have mobile version also. So, my question is what is the best approach(approved by Apple) for this kind of model? In our website version, we do payment by paypal. In my understanding, selling digital goods via paypal that is integrated within the app is not allowed(correct me if I'm wrong). Also, we have like 5000+ books on the website, so adding all books in iTunes(if it can be done) is no cake work I think. :D So help me out guys, this is my first app that involves buying and paying. After a successful payment, this book can now be read from within the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your correct, Apple does not allow any payment method for in app content that circumvents the IAP model.

You have two real options. One is to use IAP (In app purchase). This will give users the best native experience and will allow you to use apples framework BUT there are two downsides:
- Apple takes a 30% cut of all IAP revenue
- There is a chance that patent trolls Lodsys will come after you for unauthorized use of IAP (its not actually unauthorized, but they will try and argue that it is and sue you for it, google 'IAP Lodsys' for more info)

The other option that gives you more control over the payment system and gives you full revenue it to allow users to purchase books for their app on your website (The way kindle works). Not the best experience for users, but definitely best for your wallets.

Unfortunately I am not aware of any other payment methods, would be interesting to hear of some if anyone has any.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I've seen how barnes and noble sell their books in iPhone. Once the user hit the "checkout" button it fires up safari and the rest of the checkout process is done on the website. I think I can go to this direction. what do you think?

Comment: Amazon used to do that too, until Apple threatened to remove their app unless they got rid of the button. Having said that I believe the rules have now relaxed in that regard. Personally i would go the 'pay outside the app' method. Id include a button that takes them to the apyment portal in safari and, if apple rejects it, get rid of the button and just include instructions on how to purchae more books.

Comment: I think I should do it that way. We add new books from time to time and sometimes change the prices. I don't think IAP is the way to go since I don't think we can add new products in iTunes and change prices? :D

Comment: Fair enough. I think with IAP you can still change prices but you wont get anywhere near as much control over your model. Good luck with it all and please mark this answer as correct if its helped :)